# Jenkins and different Bitbucket's branches

Tags: git, github, svn, jenkins, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repo online with a few branches inside. I need to run different jobs on Jenkins by commit. In other words, if I've made a commit in branch A, run a task A will run, but if I've made the commit in branch B, task B will run.

But as far as I know the Bitbucket webhooks can't work by branches, only the repo. How do I solve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which Bitbucket plugin are you using? The [Parameterized Builds for Jenkins](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.kylenicholls.stash.parameterized-builds/server/overview) plugin have support to choose the matched branches or tags you want to trigger builds. It seems you need to have Bitbucket 5 at least to have this feature.

See more details [here](https://github.com/KyleLNicholls/parameterized-builds).

Comment: Sorry, but I have the Cloud Bitbacket.